# How to remove non/alphanumeric characters from multiple file names which differ

Tags: linux, bash, filenames, file-rename, batch-rename

How do I remove a string of alpha, numeric and non-alphanumeric characters from multiple file name, where the values differ for each file:

Example of files:

```
11SP60_H5LMLDSX7_AAGATACACG-TGTTAGCACA_L004_R1.fastq.gz
12HH32_H5LMLDSX7_TGCAATGAAT-TTACTTCTGG_L001_R2.fastq.gz
B00699_H5LMLDSX7_CCGCTCCGTT-CTTCGCCGTA_L002_R1.fastq.gz 
A80101_H5LMLDSX7_TAGGTATGTT-CTTGGTCTCG_L003_R1.fastq.gz
```

Example of what I want the output to be:

```
11SP60_L004_R1.fastq.gz
12HH32_L001_R2.fastq.gz
B00699_L002_R1.fastq.gz 
A80101_L003_R1.fastq.gz
```

I am unable to use remove function due to usage rights.
Thank you!

Comment: `f=11SP60_H5LMLDSX7_AAGATACACG-TGTTAGCACA_L004_R1.fastq.gz; echo "${f/_H*_L/_L}"`?

Comment: `sed 's/\([^_]*\)_[^_]*_[^_]*_\(.*\)/\1_\2/'` ? Or `awk -F_ '{print $1 "_" $4 "_" $5}'`?

Comment: Do you want to rename or copy the files, giving them a new name?

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop over the filenames. In bash that would be:

```
for f in *.fastq.gz ; do
    newf=$(echo $f|  sed 's/\([^_]*\)_[^_]*_[^_]*_\(.*\)/\1_\2/')
    echo "mv $f $newf"
done
```

Look at the output. It is a good idea if you're not very experienced in `bash` to try an `echo` first. Otherwise, you may get unwanted results if you make a mistake.

When you are satisfied that the new name is correct, replace the

```
echo "mv $f $newf
```

with

```
mv "$f" "$newf"
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure `bash`:

```
for file in *_*_*_*_*.fastq.gz; do
    head=${file%%_*}
    tail=${file#*_*_*_}
    echo mv "$file" "${head}_${tail}" # Drop the echo if the output looks good
done
```

This should work in POSIX shell, too. You don't have to call an external utility (like `sed` or `awk`). Bash and POSIX shell have built-in support to perform this kind of string manipulation.